# Is it acceptable to put lib folder inside module folder structure?

Tags: magento2, 3rd-party-library

Before I used this code to include some packages:

```
require_once($this->dir->getPath('lib_internal') . '/vendor/module/nuevomailer/api.php');
```

Now Magento doesn't allow to use require_once anymore so I thought that the simplest way without creating another packages just for third party libraries would be to just create lib folder inside existing vendorname/modulename folder and call it like this:

```
    class Subscriber extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel{
        protected $mailchimp;
        protected $phpmailer;
        ...
        public function _construct(
            \Vendorname\Modulename\Lib\Mailchimp $mailchimp,
            \Vendorname\Modulename\Lib\Phpmailer $phpmailer,
            ...
        function subscribe(){
            $this->mailchimp->subscribe();
        }
```

Is that acceptable method? I checked Magento modul file structure (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html) and I couldn't find lib folder. Is it allowed to put any other folder into module directory?